# Что такое паттерны и пример

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет! недавно я где-то услышал слово `паттерн`, но так и не понял что это.
Огромная просьба все тщательно разжевать)

1) Что такое паттерн?
2) Пример паттерна на с++
3) насколько часто применяют паттерны?

Comment: Попробуйте почитать [здесь](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns)

Comment: "Пример паттерна на c++", лол

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Паттерн - это некое поведение кода по заранее обусловленной схеме, для решение типовых задач. Чем больше Вы знаете таких паттернов (схем), тем меньше Вам придется изобретать велосипед для реализации задач общего назначения. Про количество паттернов и  их применение можно почитать по ссылке которую Вам оставил **Юрий Козлов** в комментарии под Ваш пост. Для большей гибкости можно добавить что любой паттерн Вы можете подстроить под свои задачи (модифицировать).
2. Примеры кода (взято из wikipedia):

Паттерн: "одиночка"

```
class Singleton
{
protected:
    static Singleton* _self;
    Singleton() {}
    virtual ~Singleton() {}

public:
    static Singleton* Instance()
    {
        if(!_self)
        {
            _self = new Singleton();
        }
        return _self;
    }

    static bool DeleteInstance()
    {
        if(_self)
        {
            delete _self;
            _self = 0;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Singleton* Singleton ::_self = 0;
```

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Паттерн: "фабричный метод" (взято из wikipedia)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Product{
  virtual string getName() = 0;
  virtual ~Product(){}
};

struct ConcreteProductA: Product{
  string getName(){return "ConcreteProductA";}
};

struct ConcreteProductB: Product{
  string getName(){return "ConcreteProductB";}
};

struct Creator{
  virtual Product* factoryMethod() = 0;
};

struct ConcreteCreatorA: Creator{
  Product* factoryMethod(){return new ConcreteProductA();}
};

struct ConcreteCreatorB: Creator{
  Product* factoryMethod(){return new ConcreteProductB();}
};

int main()
{
  ConcreteCreatorA CreatorA;
  ConcreteCreatorB CreatorB;
  // An array of creators
  Creator*creators[] = {&CreatorA, &CreatorB};
  // Iterate over creators and create products
  for(auto&& creator: creators){
    Product* product=creator->factoryMethod();
    cout << product->getName() << endl;
    delete product;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

и т.д.

3. Постоянно. Паттерны встречаются по сути в любом проекте. Просто люди которые не знают про них даже не осознают, что создали паттерн "одиночка" или "абстрактную фабрику", но по своему, исходя из своих знаний на текущий момент. Знание про то как реализовать и использовать паттерны позволяет решать эти же задачи более правильным путем с учетом уже наработанной практике сообщества.

ЗЫ. Как по мне, если есть возможность прочитайте книгу: «Head First. Паттерны проектирования.» https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20216992/ - Рекомендую! Очень низкий порог вхождения + очень доступно!

ЗЫЫ. Важно! У любого паттерна есть плюсы и минусы. Не стоит увлекаться только паттернами, Ваш код должен в первую очередь быть "чистым кодом", без контрольное использование паттернов, только усложнит Вам и другим работу с написанным решением.

Comment: Стоит скопировать примеры сюда. Ссылки могут умереть.

Comment: Вы правы. Добавил код вместо ссылок.